# Python 3 + Selenium: Clicked the element but nothing happen

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

The element was clicked and I didn't get any error but the popup ("add featured photos" popup in Facebook) is still there. It is not closed.

This is html code:

```
<div class="_5lnf uiOverlayFooter _5a8u">
   <table class="uiGrid _51mz uiOverlayFooterGrid" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody>
          <tr class="_51mx">
             <td class="_51m- prs uiOverlayFooterMessage">
             <td class="_51m- uiOverlayFooterButtons _51mw">
                <a class="_42ft _4jy0 layerCancel uiOverlayButton _4jy3 _517h _51sy" href="#" role="button">Cancel</a>
                <button class="_42ft _4jy0 layerConfirm uiOverlayButton _4jy3 _4jy1 selected _51sy" type="submit" value="1">Save</button>
             </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

And this is my code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[@class='_42ft _4jy0 layerConfirm uiOverlayButton _4jy3 _4jy1 selected _51sy']")
```

How to click "save" button to close popup ? Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can scroll to the button before clicking to it

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[@class='_42ft _4jy0 layerConfirm uiOverlayButton _4jy3 _4jy1 selected _51sy']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).perform()
button.click()
```

Comment: Shit ! I don't need to scroll because the popup was shown in main screen but your code work like a charm :)

Comment: @NGuyen Maybe "scroll" wasn't the correct term, after all the function is called "move to element".

Comment: Yeah. Thank you for making my day :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text() = 'Save']").click()
```

Comment: It shows an error: Element is not clickable at point. I think selenium clicked at another position.

Comment: It has not clicked on another position. Does the Save button perhaps have something covering the button? Such as a header, or perhaps the Cancel button?

Comment: It shows"Other element would receive the click: <div class="_3ixn"></div>". I clicked outsite popup and see <div class="_3ixn"></div> in the firebug.

Comment: That div must be somehow painted above your button.